# How to make text overlap

Tags: css, overlap, css-position

I want to make 2 DIV overlap horizontally. I want the content inside the DIV to overlap as well.
In the below example, aaaaaaa wraps around block A and the expected behavior is to have aaaaaaa starts at the left border of div B.
How can I achieve this ?

```
<div id="A" style="float:left;position:relative; background: #987321; width: 100px; height: 300px; z-index:5; "></div>`
<div id="B" style=" background: #555; width: 400px; height: 400px; ">aaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/queto_putito/8kJJa/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/R8fzq/  but this will make your text disapear. you need b div transparent or z-index need to be change

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#### CSS

```
<style>
    div.a {
        width:      100px;
        height:     300px;
    }

    div.b {
        position:   relative;
        z-index:    0;
        width:      400px;
        height:     400px;
        margin-top: -300px;
        border:     1px solid red;
    }

    div.c {
        position:   relative;
        z-index:    1;
        height:     100%;
        border:     1px solid blue;
    }
</style>
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="c">div A's content</div>
    <div class="b">div B's content xxxxx</div>
</div>
```